# Optimizing a function in R with more than one solution

Tags: r, optimization

I am attempting to optimize (minimize) a function with two parameters that should have a unique solution.

```
foo <- function(x) {
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  t=5-sqrt((0-x1)^2+(0-x2)^2);
  u=4-sqrt((0-x1)^2+(4-x2)^2);
  v=3-sqrt((3-x1)^2+(0-x2)^2);
  return(sum(t,u,v))
}    

optim(c(0,0), foo)
```

Those of you who loved middle school math may recognize the formula for the distance between two points on a Cartesian (x,y) coordinate plane. The function foo is written so that x1 is the x coordinate and x2 is the y coordinate of a point I'm trying to find. In this case, that point is (3,4). However, I'm getting a whacky output:

```
optim(c(0,0), foo)
$par
[1] -3.938866e+54  1.293779e+54

$value
[1] -1.243772e+55

$counts
function gradient 
     501       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Guess you are messing up the concept of *solution* (i.e. finding the zeroes of a function) with the one of finding the mimimum (or maximum) of a function. `optim` does the latter, while I guess you are interested in the former.

Comment: If you are trying to find the minimum then the square roots should be positive and not negative. If negative then the minimum is the farthest point from those three points.

Answer (score 1):

As is, your function has no minimum, since t, u and v decrease as x1 and x2 go farther away from the three fixed points (0,0), (0,4) and (3,0).

It seems that you want to find a point (x1,x2) that minimizes the distance to those three points. If that's the case, you should define f as:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  t = 5 + sqrt((0-x1)^2+(0-x2)^2);
  u = 4 + sqrt((0-x1)^2+(4-x2)^2);
  v = 3 + sqrt((3-x1)^2+(0-x2)^2);
  return(sum(t,u,v))
}
```

Note that the only change is `-sqrt` to `+sqrt`.

The answer is not point (3,4) as you expect, the minimum is a point inside the triangle that have those three points as vertex.

Solution:

```
> z
$par
[1] 0.7510095 0.6954136

$value
[1] 18.76643

$counts
function gradient 
      59       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

The red point is the solution:
[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was that the 3 and 4 were flipped. The other was that your differences were signed. But also the routine can converge to a local min which is not the absolute min. Instead:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  t=5-sqrt((0-x[1])^2+(0-x[2])^2);
  u=3-sqrt((0-x[1])^2+(4-x[2])^2);
  v=4-sqrt((3-x[1])^2+(0-x[2])^2);
  return(sum(abs(t),abs(u),abs(v)))
}    

optim(c(4,0), foo)
```

Comment: I could have left your x1 and x2 alone, I was just tinkering to see if they were causing some typecasting error (they were not). Output is $par
[1] 3 4

$value
[1] 1.074521e-07

$counts
function gradient 
     125       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL